# working with out of range integers in java

Tags: java, rsa

Working on a project dealing with RSA encyption and decryption and part of it is working with  this number

```
int modulus = 270653957405596110781
```

which is a 68 bit number and i know long only goes up to 64 bit, so how would i address this?

I tried the whole

```
    public static void main(String [] args){

    long modulus = 270653957405596110781L;


}
```

thing and still no luck because its a 68 bit number instead of 64 like i said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to use a `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger("270653957405596110781");
```

[Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: thanks! i can like divide and stuff on that number still right? or do i need something special for that?

Comment: @erp `modulus.divide(otherNumber);`

Answer (score 2):

Use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). It has been designed to support arbitrary large integer operations.

BTW, I hope you're not reimplementing RSA encryption by yourself. RSA is natively supported by the JDK.

Comment: thanks, but yeah thats part of what im doing, trying to get a better understanding of it so im implementing it fully!